# Query issue while using XML file in pentaho

Tags: xml, pentaho

Given the following XML file, how do I get the number of occurrences of a particular genre.  eg count(genre)?
I am writing these queries in Pentaho Report Designer. I am posting screenshots, which may help to understand how that works.

here I gave an XPath.

[image: 1]

And the output was this in the application.

[image: 2]

On giving a query like string-join(distinct-values(/catalog/book/genre),',')
I get an error

[image: 2]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
        <image>http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02445/mars_2445397b.jpg</image>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
        <image>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons /8/85/Venus_globe.jpg</image>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society.</description>
        <image>http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/saturn/saturn.jpg</image>
      </book>
      </catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generic XQuery sample:**
Hopefully it will help guide you some. I have no idea what Pentaho Report Designer is.

```
    let $catalog := <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
        <image>http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02445/mars_2445397b.jpg</image>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
        <image>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons /8/85/Venus_globe.jpg</image>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society.</description>
        <image>http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/saturn/saturn.jpg</image>
    </book>
</catalog>

return 
  element {"genre-count"}{
  for $genre in fn:distinct-values($catalog/book/genre)
     return element {"genre"}{ 
       attribute {"name"}{$genre},
       fn:count($catalog/book/genre[.=$genre])
     }
    }
```

Results:

```
<genre-count>
  <genre name="Computer">1</genre>
  <genre name="Fantasy">2</genre>
</genre-count>
```

Comment: Can't use this in Pentaho as far as I can see. :( Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Like David Ennis, I'm not familiar with Pentaho's XQuery support. From the very few mentions of XQuery I've been able to locate from Pentaho's documentation, forums, and Github repository, it appears Pentaho uses a very capable XQuery engine, Saxon. Saxon should give you the capability to run generic XPath and FLWOR expressions on your XML data, but what limits Pentaho imposes or what contexts it assumes are unclear to me. I would suggest starting with a basic XPath expression - the building block of any XQuery:

```xq
/catalog/book/title
```

This should return:

```xml
<title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
<title>Midnight Rain</title>
<title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
```

If this returns the expected results, try the following expression, which adds functions from the standard library, `string-join()` and `distinct-values()`:

```xq
string-join(distinct-values(/catalog/book/genre), ', ')
```

This should return something like:

```
Computer, Fantasy
```

If this returns the expected results, try a FLWOR expression:

```xq
for $genre in distinct-values(/catalog/book/genre)
let $books-in-genre := /catalog/book[genre = $genre]
return
    <genre label="{$genre}" book-count="{count($books-in-genre)}"/>
```

If this fails, you may need to wrap your results in a single root node:

```xq
<genres>{
    for $genre in distinct-values(/catalog/book/genre)
    let $books-in-genre := /catalog/book[genre = $genre]
    return
        <genre label="{$genre}" book-count="{count($books-in-genre)}"/>
}</genres>
```

If you encounter any problems with these, please post any error messages you receive, and this might help.

Comment: I updated my question with the error. please take a look

Comment: The error message indicates Pentaho doesn't understand the `distinct-values` or `string-join` functions. Perhaps it expects these with the namespace prefix, `fn:`.  Could you try changing these functions to `fn:distinct-values` and `fn:string-join`?  If this fails, try wrapping the results in an element node, e.g., `<result>{string-join(distinct-values(/catalog/book/genre), ', ')}</result>` - or the `fn:`-prefixed versions of each function.